# How to split on white spaces not between quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string on white spaces only (`\s`), but that are not between a "quoted" section.

I am matching all text in between these quoted sections in the following manner:

```
(['"`]).*?\1
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5I209k/2)

However, when I try to add this as a negative lookahead, to only split on white spaces outside of those quotes, I can't get it to work:

```
\s(?!(['"`]).*?\1)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5I209k/3)

How can I only split on the white spaces that are not in "quotes"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)
```

You can use this regex with `lookahead` to split upon.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/5I209k/4

or if mixed tick types.

https://regex101.com/r/5I209k/7

Comment: This doesn't work very well with miss-matched or nested quotes. But for a well balanced and non-nested quotes it works like a charm. E.g. `Split on spaces, except "for this, and 'this section'", and \`ignore this too\`.` and `Split on spaces, except "for this', and 'this section', and \`ignore this too\`."`

Comment: @Marcus i guess OP can tell if such a scenario would occur or not.Also none of the answers would work in that case.

Comment: of course, it was just to inform future readers of the edge cases. As mentioned, it works like charm for the example string.

Comment: Just so you know intent, the quotes must be in pairs. I have been trying to convert a complex `replace` chain with a split regular expression to simplify the process. I am working on a code parser, and need to know when a developer is intending for a string to be passed to a function, or if it should be an object. The spaces represent the separate arguments being passed to a function. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: what if i want to be able to escape quotes like this: `\"`? this wouldn't work

Comment: @vks can you show a sample regex? i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @vks https://regex101.com/r/KAx8LX/2

how can i make it split in the areas where it says `should split here`?

Comment: @RedGuy11 https://regex101.com/r/35YZkm/1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to exclude entries *within* the group. Instead of using a negative lookahead you could do it like this:

```
(\S*(?:(['"`]).*?\2)\S*)\s?|\s
```

Basically what it does is to:

- captures any non-whitespace characters

  - that may contain a quoted string
  - and is optionally directly followed by any non-whitespace (e.g a comma after the quote).
- then matches an optional trailing whitespace

OR

- matches a single whitespace

Capture group1 will then contain an as long as possible sequences of all non-whitespace characters (unless they are within quotes). This can thus be used with the replacement group `\1\n` to replace your desired whitespaces with a newline.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/A4HswJ/1

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1kjudmg/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simpler approach, no need of advanced features:

```
'([^']|\\.)*'|"([^"]|\\.)*"|`([^`]||\.)*`|\S*
```

meaning:

- a single-quoted section `'([^']|\\.)*'`
- or `|` a double-quoted section `"([^"]|\\.)*"`
- or `|` a back-quoted section (can't place it inline in SO markdown)
- or `|` an un-quoted section `\S*`

This will separate also quoted parts. If this is not wanted you can instead use

```
('([^']|\\.)*'|"([^"]|\\.)*"|`([^`]||\.)*`|\S)+
```

i.e. find sequences of tokens where each token is either a non-whitespace or a quoted section.

Comment: Per the example, wouldn't this break `"for this",` into two parts (`"for this"` and `,`)?

Comment: @MarcusMarco not the seccond one

@6502 how can I make it work with escaped quotes? aka `\"`?

Comment: @RedGuy11: The regexp `"([^"]|\\.)*"` already handles escaped double-quotes (the internal part means "either not a double quote or a backslash followed by anything")